Doubts about three skew lines in 3D
In 3D, non-intersecting, non-coplaner, non-parallel lines are called skew lines.
Question no. 1:
Consider, top 3 planes $(\Pi_1,\Pi_2,\Pi_3)$ of a tetrahedron leaving the base plane. The edge line $L_1$ due to the intersction $\Pi_2$ and $\Pi_3$; and similarly, the other two edges $L_2$ and $L_3$ are pairwise coplaner. Together $L_1,L_2,L_3$ are non-coplaner but intersecting (concurrent) at the tip of the tetrahedrom where 3 planes $\Pi_1,\Pi_2,\Pi_3$ meet. Can we call these 3 lines skew lines?
Question no. 2:
In 3D, can a line $L_4$ intersect 3 skew lines $L_1,L_2,L_3$? Or, can three points $P_1,P_2,P_3$ on three skew lines $L_1,L_2,L_3$ be collinear?
Both analytic and geometric examples will be more helpful.
Edit: In this regard, three edges of a prism are non-coplaner (are pairwise coplaner), can be called  skew lines as they do not intersect.

Please include a picture/diagram if possible.

About question 2, the answer is yes. The locus of the variable line $L_4$ should be a hyperbold of one sheet. see this answer.

An example for #2: consider a line intersected by three parallel planes.  Pick three lines, one in each plane such that they go thru the point of intersection of the corresponding plane with the original line and they are not parallel to each other.

@Vasili Thanks for the example.

Q1: According to the definition you gave at the top, if the three lines intersect, we cannot call them skew lines.
Q2: Consider the lines $L_1: \lambda(1,0,0)$, $L_2: \mu(1,1,0)+(0,0,1)$ and $L_3: \gamma(0,1,0)+(0,0,2)$. They are skew according to your definition above, but the $z$ axis intersects them all. Also the points $P_1=(0,0,0)$, $P_2=(0,0,1)$ and $P_3=(0,0,2)$ the are in these three skew lines respectively and they are collinear (they belong to the $z$ axis.)
